# node-gd: synchronous savePng() not returning error

Tags: node.js, gd

I am using GD with `node-gd` for a batch image converter script. The script saves its output to PNG. But it seems that `node-gd` only returns an error object if `savePng()` is called asynchronously. A synchronous call always returns the image's parameters, regardless if it was successfully saved or not.

So if I do this:

```
img.savePng(filename, err => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

it will properly print the error message. But if I do this:

```
let err = img.savePng(filename);
console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
```

then I always get this:

```
{
   "colorsTotal": 0,
   "interlace": false,
   "height": 1920,
   "width": 1080,
   "trueColor": 1
}
```

How can I detect an error with a synchronous call?

Comment: The async version uses `fs.writeFile` while the sync version is handled by libgd, by C++ code. You could wrap the synchronous call in a try-catch maybe?

Comment: Oh my I've already forgotten this bug, but thanks anyway :) I think I tried the try-catch to no avail.